# What happens if I don't tell immigration where I was?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

If someone was in another country for study purposes for 6/7 months, and for 3 months of this time he went back home to sell his home furniture and give back the rent money, and they did not tell anyone, for example Canadian Immigration, what would happen? Would they understand?

Comment: So you are from country X and have a visa to study in Canada for 6-7 months, but halfway through you want to return to country X to deal with domestic issues and then continue your studies in Canada? And you want to know if you can do this without telling the Canadian immigration authorities?

Comment: Or were your studies elsewhere and now you want to apply to Canada without revealing some or all of your previous travel history? Has your study visa expired?

Comment: first too much thanks for your reply,then let me i clarify what i mean, i was 4+3 months in India first 4 months i though it is good anyway i come back and decided never go there again,but i return there to sell my things and return to my country ,...i dont want to apply for study in Canada...my question is about Immigration process like Express Entry

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes for Immigration i'm not tend to tell them ,i don't have any problem with PCC [i have that],thanks

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for Your reply it is under EE process not study visa

Comment: I still don't really understand what you are saying, but the general rule is, if the officer asks you anything, never lie! If he doesn't ask you, you don't need to tell, but if you tell something, make sure it's the truth. Lying can result in deportation or even a ban.

Comment: Why would you *want* to lie? Are you worried that Canadian immigration will interpret your actions as demonstrating lack of ties to India? If so, you really need to handle that directly rather than lying about it. Where are your ties? If you now consider, say, Belgium to be your home, then gather evidence of ties to Belgium so that Canadian immigration is not worried that you want to stay in Canada. Second, you might be able to couch your activities in more broad (but honest) language, like "visiting family and handling financial transactions", and wait to see if they want more details.

Comment: @dunni thanks i was for 6 months for study in other country
i want to apply immigration process
i'm not tend to tell about that 6 months
and might be in form ask something like:have you been other country in past 10 years ? 
officer will not ask
my query is will they can understand ?or no

Comment: Well, if they ask in a form if you have been in another country, and you say no, it's a lie which can result in visa denial and even a ban. So again, if they ask you that question, answer truthfully.

Comment: @RobertColumbia thanks about why?let me i say completely but short: for that 7 months my employer gives me a recommendation letter which this guy 2 years works here and that 7 months is in this time[i think i reach my purpose ] so if i say 7 months i was another place for any purpose they ask why in your employer letter you claim working ? one guy told me i can say that 7 months was >>Business mission<<but i'm not sure whether i can or not or will they ask or not

Comment: @dunni i promise this is last time i ask :) how they can understand where i was exactly ?

Comment: E.g. by looking in your passport and checking what stamps you have, by exchanging immigration data with other countries, by looking how you respond (those officers usually are pretty good in telling lies), etc.

Comment: @tyran0 you can ask the employer to qualify the letter with a statement that you were "on holiday" for seven months. Alternately, you can simply tell the immigration official, "umm, I have this recommendation letter, but for some reason they didn't put down that I was on holiday during most of Spring/Summer 2018 (shrug)."

Comment: @RobertColumbia Oh,more close to real , thanks Sir
and you think would they accept this time as my work experience ? or 7 months will deducted :D

Comment: @dunni thanks dear i think not all Country database has been exchanged with each other ,it's good reason to search
but telling truth is better i understand

Comment: @tyran0 it depends on what you want to do. If you are very close to a minimum cutoff (e.g. you want a visa that requires X months of experience), then you probably want to engage an immigration attorney to determine what documentary evidence you require to prove it. If you just want to have a nice trip, just be honest.

Comment: @RobertColumbia thanks for this much of perception Sir
for Express Entry needs 3 years [36 months] work experience  up to now i talking with you i have more than 50 months ,so whether they deduct or not i'm not loosing anything[see please 50-7=43 > 36] still i earn scores
but you know this is not something for hidden its personal things i don't tend they understand 
thanks again

Comment: @RobertColumbia express entry is an immigration scheme, so ties to another country are not relevant (and this question is therefore off-topic here, so I'm voting to close in favor of [Expatriates.SE]).